# A fiber run is too expensive, so why not use some POE switches to extend the Ethernet run?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, cat6, power-over-ethernet

Recently at work, we encountered a client with a Ethernet run over 500ft long. As you may know, Ethernet cables are only rated for the maximum of 300ft.  In the process of quoting a fiber run, we decided to look for a cheaper alternative.

Here is the real question: Using a [Ubiquiti US-8 Unifi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MZ32B1B) Switch, is it possible to use Poe to power one of the switches at the close end of the run, and (using the Poe pass through on the first to power it) put a second on the far end?

Comment: I can’t believe your suggested solution is cheaper than a relatively short run of fibre.

Comment: Fiber run ~ 6K;  Poe switches ~ 400$. problem is the client isn't willing to pay the price on the fiber run...

Comment: I don't know about that, but have you looked into Ethernet Extenders? You can easily cover these distances for a few hundred bucks on that 500' cable run, heck, even on a 2500' cable run.

Comment: even with cable extenders you sacrifice the speed of said connection for distance, so yes you could, but for this example we need gigabit connection.

Comment: Assuming that you want a single cable, an Ethernet Extender on each end will probably work for you.  Assuming it's indoors, it should be kept away from water, moving objects, walkways for people, running motors, electrical mains, and other data cables.  It must be securely fastened to the wall / ceiling / plenum in many places, see your local building codes.

Comment: Yes, Extenders would work but Im not positive there would be a place to plug them in. Hence the POE question this is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. There are also special PoE extenders that are specifically designed for this purpose: one PD port, one PSE port.

6K for a 150 m fiber run isn't serious though. You can buy an already terminated multi-mode cable for less than $200.